# Complicated MySQL JOIN query

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am developing a HelpDesk system for my company in which I have a series of related tables as in the following image:

[image: relaciones de tablas]

The main table is `tickets`, where I store the basic data of the ticket, including its author `id_pers_empleado`.

The most important table is `tickets_asignaciones`, which is where you indicate whether the ticket is assigned to an employee (we'll call it an agent in this table) `id_agente` or to a team `id_equipo`.

The teams are defined in the `tickets_equipos` table and the agents that make up each team are indicated in the `tickets_equipos_agentes` table, which relates the `tickets_equipos` and `empleados` tables.
What I need is a query that allows me to get all the tickets ...

1. That have as author a certain worker X (`WHERE tickets.id_pers_empleado = X`).
2. Or they are assigned directly to that worker X (`WHERE tickets_asignaciones.id_pers_empleado = X`).
3. Or that they are assigned to a team to which said worker X belongs:

```sql
WHERE 
    tickets.id_pers_empleado IN (
        SELECT 
            tickets_equipos_agentes.id_pers_empleado 
        FROM 
            tickets_equipos_agentes 
        WHERE 
            tickets_asignaciones.id_equipo = tickets_equipos_agentes.id_pers_empleado
   )
 AND
   tickets.id_pers_empleado = X
```

(I'm not sure if the above is correct, probably not).

I could do this by doing multiple independent queries with PHP and `foreach` loops, but I don't want to overload the server with so many requests and I need a query that does all the work at once.

I have already tried so many JOINS in different ways that now I am dizzy and stuck. I can't find the correct way to write the query correctly. Also, I don't know if I should use subqueries in some way to achieve what I am trying to do.

I don't think the problem is in the relationship or the layout of the tables, but rather in my lack of knowledge about such complex queries.

Does anyone have any ideas in mind of how to solve it? Thank you.

---

I'll put the little dataset with which I am working.

#### TICKETS TABLE

Here the `id_pers_empleado` is the author of the ticket, that is, the user who created the record.

```
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| id          | fecha               | titulo                                       | id_tipo | id_pers_empleado |
+=============+=====================+==============================================+=========+==================+
| 00000000001 | 2020/07/26 08:24:40 | Ticket de autoría propia (sin asignación)    | 01      | 00000005         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 2020/08/08 16:32:43 | Ticket asignado a un solo agente             | 02      | 00000011         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 2020/08/08 19:19:38 | Ticket asignado a un equipo                  | 02      | 00000012         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000004 | 2020/08/08 19:24:16 | Ticket asignado a varios agentes             | 02      | 00000004         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000005 | 2020/08/08 19:27:21 | Ticket asignado a un equipo y varios agentes | 01      | 00000001         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
```

#### TICKETS_ASIGNACIONES TABLE

In this table, `id_pers_empleado` is the person who assigns the ticket and `id_agente` is the person  whom the ticket is assigned. It may be the case that `id_agente` is empty, in which case it is mandatory to fill in `id_equipo`.

Here `id_pers_empleado` cannot be empty because it is trying to know who is the one who has assigned / escalated the ticket. It is also possible that a particular ticket does not have any assignment, either because the ticket is new and it has not yet been decided who it should be assigned to, or because it is an informational ticket and does not require intervention by any agent.

```
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id_ticket   | id_pers_empleado | id_equipo | id_agente |
+=============+==================+===========+===========+
| 00000000002 | 00000011         |           | 00000005  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000003 | 00000002         | 02        |           |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000004 | 00000003         |           | 00000003  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000004 | 00000002         |           | 00000002  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001         | 04        |           |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001         |           | 00000001  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001         |           | 00000004  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

#### TICKETS_EQUIPOS TABLE

It is the bridge between `tickets_asignaciones` and `tickets_equipos_agentes`, and it will also save other data such as the icon, color, and who is the team leader, but they are not relevant so I have not included them.

```
+-------------+--------------+
| id          | nombre       |
+=============+==============+
| 00000000001 | Contabilidad |
+-------------+--------------+
| 00000000002 | RRHH         |
+-------------+--------------+
| 00000000003 | Calidad      |
+-------------+--------------+
| 00000000004 | Técnico      |
+-------------+--------------+
```

#### TICKETS_EQUIPOS_AGENTES TABLE

Here the `id_pers_empleado` is the worker that belongs to a team from the table above. The same worker / agent can be in several teams at the same time.

```
+-------------+------------------+
| id_equipo   | id_pers_empleado |
+=============+==================+
| 00000000001 | 00000001         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000001 | 00000098         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000006         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000007         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000008         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 00000001         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 00000011         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 00000098         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000004 | 00000005         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000004 | 00000034         |
+-------------+------------------+
```

---

### Approximation so far

The best way I've found so far to display the results I'm looking for is this:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.id_pers_empleado autor,
    t1.titulo,
    t2.id_agente,
    t2.id_equipo,
    t3.nombre nombreEquipo
FROM
    tickets t1
LEFT JOIN
    tickets_asignaciones t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_ticket 
LEFT JOIN
    tickets_equipos t3 ON t2.id_equipo = t3.id
WHERE
    t1.id_pers_empleado = 5
OR
    t2.id_agente = 5
OR
    t1.id_pers_empleado IN (
        SELECT
            id_pers_empleado 
        FROM
            tickets_equipos_agentes t4
            LEFT JOIN tickets_equipos t5 ON t4.id_equipo = t5.id
        WHERE t4.id_equipo = t3.id
    )
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

The operation resultset is this:

```
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| id_ticket   | autor    | titulo                                       | id_agente | id_equipo | nombreEquipo |
+=============+==========+==============================================+===========+===========+==============+
| 00000000001 | 00000005 | Ticket de autoría propia (sin asignación)    |           |           |              |
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000011 | Ticket asignado a un solo agente             | 5         |           |              |
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001 | Ticket asignado a un equipo y varios agentes |           | 4         | Técnico      |
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

So far it seems that it works but I don't know if I am doing it in the best way or there is something that could be improved from the query. Also is some situations I don't see the correct results. And I'm  breaking mad.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and note that `3` is no less readable than `0000000000003`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with outer joins should look like this I think:

```
select *
from tickets t
left join tickets_asignaciones ta on ta.id_ticket = t.id
left join tickets_equipos_agentes tea on tea.id_equipo = ta.id_equipo
left join tickets_equipos te ON te.id = tea.id_equipo
where t.id_pers_empleado = 5 or ta.id_agente = 5 or tea.id_pers_empleado = 5
order by t.fecha;
```

The `WHERE` clause can be shortened to:

```
where 5 in (t.id_pers_empleado, ta.id_agente, tea.id_pers_empleado)
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfd9a1ee71542fbe57987355289dd946

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this. While I see that there isn't much explanation in my answer, I don't know exactly what I should explain, because the query is straight-forward and should be easy to understand. I've added a demo to show the query is selecting the requested data.

Comment: I think your response is truly better and faster than the final I reached. Also I did some tests and it worked propperly. In my final solution I found the way to know also the relation of the worker with the ticket (author, straight assign, team assign) which is a bonus to what I need, but your response is perfectly valid and I could use it in my final implementation. I'll mark as response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have 4 possibilities, and I would just UNION them.

1-Person was the author of the ticket

```
select
        T.id,
        T.id_pers_empleado autor,
        T.Titulo,
        E.nombre
    from
        Tickets T
            JOIN Empleados E
                on T.id_pers_empleado = E.id
    where
        T.id_pers_empleado = 5
```

2-From Tickets_Asignaciones, the person could be in any of 3 positions...
First option, they are the direct id_pers_empleado

```
select
        T.id,
        T.id_pers_empleado autor,
        T.Titulo,
        E.nombre
    from
        Tickets_Asignaciones TA
            JOIN Tickets T
                on TA.id_ticket = T.id
                JOIN Empleados E
                    on TA.id_pers_empleado = E.id
    where
        TA.id_pers_empleado = 5
```

3-From Tickets_Asignaciones, the person could be in any of 3 positions...
Second option, they are the direct AGENTE

```
select
        T.id,
        T.id_pers_empleado autor,
        T.Titulo,
        E.nombre
    from
        Tickets_Asignaciones TA
            JOIN Tickets T
                on TA.id_ticket = T.id
                JOIN Empleados E
                    on TA.id_pers_empleado = E.id
    where
        TA.id_agente = 5
```

4-From Tickets_Asignaciones, the person could be in any of 3 positions...
Third option, they are the secondarily associated via the equipos association. We can actually skip the tickets_equipos since the tickets_equipos_agentes  already has the ID in question, I can get via

```
select
        T.id,
        T.id_pers_empleado autor,
        T.Titulo,
        E.nombre
    from
        tickets_equipos_agentes TEA
            JOIN Tickets_Asignaciones TA
                on TEA.id_equipo = TA.id_equipo
                JOIN Tickets T
                    on TA.id_ticket = T.id
                    JOIN Empleados E
                        on TA.id_pers_empleado = E.id
    where
        TEA.id_pers_empleado = 5
```

So, by doing a UNION, if the value already exists from one query, it should be skipped from any other, such as a person is both author, and found by equipo association.  It should just return the ticket once. A Union ALL would actually return multiple records PER query that it qualified from. Additionally, you could do DISTINCT which would also prevent the same ticket showing up.

```
[query 1]
UNION
[query 2]
UNION
[query 3]
UNION
[query 4]
```

To help the queries, Tickets would have the obvious index on the ID.  Also, have an index on the "ID_Pers_Empleado".  The remaining queries, I would ensure Tickets_Asignaciones have individual indexes on the id_pers_empleado, id_equipo and id_agente... Again, 3 indexes for each individual query for join optimization on them respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Following different approaches, I finally reached a solution which works propperly and I'll share it here for other proggrammers:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        'autor' relacion, -- added a "relation" field to get which case is occurring
        t.* 
    FROM 
        tickets t
    WHERE
        id_pers_empleado = $id_pers_empleado -- PHP var to set the desired id_pers_empleado
UNION   
    SELECT 
        'asignado directamente',
        t.* 
    FROM 
        tickets t
        INNER JOIN tickets_asignaciones ta ON ta.id_ticket = t.id
    WHERE
        ta.id_agente = $id_pers_empleado -- PHP var to set the desired id_pers_empleado
UNION
    SELECT
        'asignado al equipo',
        t.* 
    FROM 
        tickets t
        INNER JOIN tickets_asignaciones ta ON ta.id_ticket = t.id
        INNER JOIN tickets_equipos e ON e.id = ta.id_equipo
        INNER JOIN tickets_equipos_agentes ea ON ea.id_equipo = e.id
    WHERE
        ea.id_pers_empleado = $id_pers_empleado -- PHP var to set the desired id_pers_empleado
) sq1
GROUP BY id -- grouping to avoid duplicated values on different cases occurring at once
ORDER BY id -- could order by timestamp, but I prefer by ticket ID
```

If you think there's a better implementation, please let me know.